Conditional use of std::move
I'm trying to forward an r-value reference from a template class Foo to another template class Bar as follows:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Ts>
struct Bar {
   void do_something(Ts... things) {
      std::cout << "Got " << sizeof...(Ts) << " things" << std::endl;
   }
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
   void do_something(Ts... things) {
      m_bar.do_something(things...);
   }

   Bar<Ts...> m_bar;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   Foo<std::string&, std::string&&> foo;

   std::string hello1("Hello");
   std::string hello2("Howdy");

   foo.do_something(hello1, std::move(hello2));
   return 0;
}

However, when we get to Foo::do_something, the 2nd argument needs to be moved again. I can't use std::move here because that would also move the 1st argument, for example:
m_bar.do_something(std::move(things)...);

So, is there a way to move only the 2nd argument?

You could use a forwarding reference and perfect forwarding in order to copy the first argument and move the second in the second call:
template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
   template <typename... Us>
   void do_something(Us&&... things) {
//                   ^^^^
//             forwarding reference

      m_bar.do_something(std::forward<Us>(things)...);
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                         copy first, move second
   }

   Bar<Ts...> m_bar;
};

Note that the references in Foo<std::string&, std::string&&> foo; should most probably not be references here but it depends on how you use them later.
If that declaration is actually what you'd like to have, you don't have to make do_something a function template but can reuse the Ts... in the class template parameter list:
template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
   void do_something(Ts... things) {
      m_bar.do_something(std::forward<Ts>(things)...);
   }

   Bar<Ts...> m_bar;
};


You don't have to make do_something a template of its own, you can reuse the template parameters from Foo.

@Ted Lyngmo I was hoping to avoid introducing additional template parameters. Maybe something like a templated version of std::move that works like std::move depending on the outcome of std::enable_ifstd::is_rvalue_reference

That sounds a lot like std::forward. You could create overloads for all four combinations if you don't want it as a function template, but why don't you want that?

@TedLyngmo I probably should have mentioned this in my initial question but I also want to be able to forward arguments to a lambda expression, and those aren't templated until C++20.

@JasonFernandez Without lambda templates, how are you planning to forward the arguments with the value category intact?

@TedLyngmo Not sure, maybe with polymorphic lambdas.

@JasonFernandez Generic lambdas wasn't a thing until C++14

Ah yes, you're right.

@HolyBlackCat Sorry, I didn't see your comment Yesterday. Yes, sure, one could std::forward<Ts>(things)...  if this Foo<std::string&, std::string&&> is actually what OP wants. I suspect it to be a mistake, but if it's not, just std::forward<Ts>(things).... Updated the answer with that.

It is not std::move you want but std::forward:
template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
   void do_something(Ts... things) {
      m_bar.do_something(std::forward<Ts>(things)...);
   }
   Bar<Ts...> m_bar;
};

Demo
It is generally used with forwarding reference, but it is not mandatory ;-)
